# XIB not outletting to class

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I'm trying to make a template for a view I'll be using multiple times with a XIB file. I need to be able to change the label inside the view so I'm trying to make a custom class for the view, but when I try connect the label as an outlet I'm getting the error: `Could not insert new outlet connection`. Here's why I mean:

[image: eventCell]

I made the class of the XIB's view to the `AddEventView`, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Just create the @IBOutlet manually in your source code and then drag to the view controller icon to connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

- Clean project using Product > clean
- Close/reopen Xcode
- Delete the Derived Data folder (Preferences > Locations and clicking the gray arrow by the Derived Data folder, then delete)
- Delete `AddEventView`, remove reference (do not move to trash). Then add it back again.